# Listing localhost computer directories on a website

Tags: javascript, file-io, file-management

If I open a website, how I can view my own computer's contents on that site? I'm thinking Javascript, but how would I do this? This would be for like a file manager.

Example: Opening example.com and have a navigator for my computer's files.

Comment: Yes, but if PHP is server side, I don't think it can be done. I am meaning to get the files on my computer, such as when one clicks an upload button.

Comment: Could you provide more details? In general, websites are blocked from opening files on clients' computers, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Read this:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750032/reading-file-contents-on-the-client-side-in-javascript-in-various-browsers][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750032/reading-file-contents-on-the-client-side-in-javascript-in-various-browsers

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript.  If you are in HTML 5, you have options: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, you can't access a computer's file system from the browser via Javascript.

However, to answer your question literally, you could do this (in your console):

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'file';
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

Scroll to the bottom of the page and you'll see a file input field.

This will allow you to browse your computer's files from the webpage.

Comment: Not unless you use a Java or Flash plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to access (potentially) ANY site's client/visitor's file system?
This is NOT possible, otherwise it would be a HUGE security breach.
If you could do it, anybody else could do it too. Imagine you yourself visiting some obscure site somewhere (it may be in pop-up even) and then some months later discovering that all your personal information that you had on your computer is available for sale.

Comment: I was thinking listing them client side - not seen by the server.

Comment: This http://www.antionline.com/archive/index.php/t-236772.html (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=JavaScript+display+content+of+c%3A+drive)  was possible some years ago. I did not try if it still works

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understand

1. You run example.com and want to show your filesystem to the public

   - Easy. Run apache/nginx with some weird document root and put all files there.
   - [CHECK] Not sure if you can run apache/nginx with / as document root.
2. You run example.com and want to show visitors filesystem to himself

   - That will be a major security issue. JS cant do that in any way.