# open file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to open a file using jQuery. Here is my HTML,

```
<button onclick='load();'>load</button>
```

Here is my js code:

```
function load() {
  var fileSelector = $('<input id="load" type = "file" multiple />');
  fileSelector.click();
  //code here to get the files ...
}
```

Now I want to get the loaded files, what should I do?

Comment: you can't do that unless otherwise you are using a backend language such as php,asp.net etc..

Comment: In modern browsers you can read a file that's been interactively selected by the user but you cannot arbitrarily set the file yourself (for obvious reasons ..)

Comment: The code to get the files does not necessarily be exactly there. I just want to know how I can get the files.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750032/reading-file-contents-on-the-client-side-in-javascript-in-various-browsers

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get the loaded files"?

Answer (score 6):

The HTML5 File Api (http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/) allows opening files, however the files must be selected by the User for security.

If you need to open a file without user interaction, then it is necessary to do this on the server side with a language like PHP for example.

Comment: Do you mean I must use include `<input type='file'> in the html?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution
I used the file type input and then use the Jquery trigger function to trigger the click event for file input.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#btnFile").click(function(){
    $("#file").trigger("click");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <input id="file" type="file" hidden/>
 <button id="btnFile">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? How do you "get the loaded files" using that code? Why do you need to trigger a click on a hidden field?

Comment: My apologies, actually I searched for a problem that somewhat similar to this, what I'm trying to do is to open the select file dialog using file input in jquery and that is my solution for that. I used the keyword "Open file input using jquery" for searching and I thought this post is related to my search and then realized I was wrong for posting this answer.

Comment: Please add all such explanation to the answer itself, not to the comment section

Answer (score 0):

You can open JSON file with JavaScript and use `fetch('json_file patch'`) .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).