# Javascript text select from array (interval)

Tags: javascript

How would I make the following change at an interval, say, 500, as opposed to being on page load?

I'm assuming this is doable

```
var textarray = [
"1",
"2",
"3",
"4",
"5"
];

function RndText() {
    var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);
    document.getElementById('ShowText').innerHTML=textarray[rannum];
}

window.onload = function() { RndText(); }
```

Would there be a way to make the script read from say, an external .txt file? As opposed to an Array within the document itself?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use setInterval() to accomplish what you are looking for. Simply call your function from within your function to ensure that it will continue to run after x seconds.

you can save this javascript into somefile.js and simply put this in your html file, `<script src="somefile.js"></script>`

```
var textarray = [
"1",
"2",
"3",
"4",
"5"
];

function RndText() {
    //wait 5 seconds
    setInterval(function(){
        var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);
        document.getElementById('ShowText').innerHTML=textarray[rannum];
    }, 5000);
}

window.onload = RndText;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly first time round and thanks for the tip regarding the <script> tag!

Comment: but the rest of the answer doesn't fit what you need?

Comment: Oh nono, it does, it works fine - what I meant by my comment was that I didn't need to ask any further questions as I have had to do previously with other questions

Worked straight away as intended

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you need to add a setInterval call. (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

```
var textarray = [
"1",
"2",
"3",
"4",
"5"
];

function RndText() {
    var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);
    document.getElementById('ShowText').innerHTML=textarray[rannum];
}

window.onload = function() { setInterval(RndText, 500); }
```

For your second question, file reading is tricky and not generally a good idea if not truly necessary. This other question should be helpful: [Reading file contents on the client-side in javascript in various browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750032/reading-file-contents-on-the-client-side-in-javascript-in-various-browsers)

Comment: This worked too, but I did however use the first answer, first. Thank you for your tip about trying to read from an external source though.