# reading file contents on client side using web browsers

Tags: javascript, windows, html, web, custom-protocol

I have a software installed on each of my clients computer , the software defines new protocol named when my client invoke the protocol form the browser the software will run in there computer and perform some file transfer operation.

for example if a client issued `LPL://-s 109.107.108.7 -f c:\tmp\file.big` in the browser the software will run and will transfer `file.big` to the server.

now i have a problem in locating the full file path in the client side , I understood that modern browsers prevent getting the full path for security reasons , however i need to read the files content of my client using web .

Is there a work around to solve this issuse

Comment: You can't do that - _"But I need to!"_ - oh now you can... No, this is not possible from a web browser. Try searching. If you really, really must and you can control the clients, either use a Flash/Silverlight/Java applet or a Desktop app.

Comment: ok , is there a way to create or get a fake path to reach the content so i can upload it with my software?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading file contents on the client-side in javascript in various browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750032/reading-file-contents-on-the-client-side-in-javascript-in-various-browsers)