# How to add file attachment and preview in text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chat

I am creating a chat box, that chat box have emoji and file attachment button.

Now the emoji is correctly work but the file attachment preview not show in text area any idea or any plugin for file attach in text area.

My text area write in emoji code

```
<p class="lead emoji-picker-container" style="margin-top:35px;">
    <textarea class="form-control textarea-control" rows="3" placeholder="Type your message here..." data-emojiable="true" style="height:150px;"></textarea>
</p
```

Anyone please help the preview show in text area

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: found the following with the similar problem statement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750032/reading-file-contents-on-the-client-side-in-javascript-in-various-browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="upload">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <input type="file" id="upload" style="display:none">
</label>
```

Comment: its ok, how to show the preview inside the text area.