# FormData console logs [object FormData ] and not the actual file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I have the following code for, uploading the file using ajax because I don't want to use form action . But I unable to do so. The code is :

```
Select xml file to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="uploadFile">
<input type="submit" id="upload_xml" value="Upload Xml">
```

The ajax code is:

```
$('#upload_xml').on('click', function() {

var file_data = $('#uploadFile').prop('files')[0];      
var form_data = new FormData();
console.log('hi'+file_data); // this gives [object File]
form_data.append('file', file_data);
console.log('yoyo'+form_data);  // this gives  [object FormData]              
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',
    dataType: 'text',  
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,                         
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response){
        alert(response); 
    }
 });
```

});

I saw many discussions on various threads, but none work for me. I have done this before without any error, I don't know what is the error :( where I am wrong here. Is there any js file that I need to include??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading file contents on the client-side in javascript in various browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750032/reading-file-contents-on-the-client-side-in-javascript-in-various-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace **+** with **,** You need also to read the file first & extract its content

```
  var file = $('#uploadFile').prop('files')[0];
    var file_data = '';
if (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        file_data = evt.target.result;
    }
    reader.onerror = function (evt) {
        file_data = "error reading file";
    }
}
    var form_data = new FormData();
    console.log('hi',file_data);
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    console.log('yoyo',form_data.get('file'));
```

Comment: @Ara does this solve your problem? otherwise I'm obliged to delete my answer

Comment: I did , but I get FromData{} on console. It shouldn't be empty right?? and only hi and yoyo are alerted, why is this so?? Can u help please

Comment: @Ara can you check again please?

Comment: It logs hi C:\fakepath\ER_diagram.xml and  yoyo C:\fakepath\ER_diagram.xml

Comment: unexpected identifier on  var file = $('#uploadFile')document.getElementById("fileToUpload").files[0]; This is not correct, fileToUpload is name not id. And I beleive $('#uploadFile') does same work as getElementById('uploadFile'). why to write twice?

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned code:

```
 for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ", " + pair[1]);
      }
```