# Is there any way to console.log the content of an html object?

Tags: javascript, html-object

Let's consider we have two files namely **object.html** & **load.txt**.

object.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <body>
    <object data="load.txt"></object>
  </body>
  </html>
```

load.txt

```
   You have to load me !
```

Now, when I open the **object.html** in browser window, the content of load.txt file is shown ( as usual ), but I want the content also to show in the console, saying *"The content of the text file you loaded :"* and the content after that. But I am not understanding, how to console.log the content of the txt file. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly **console.log()** the content of the file.

For that, you need to read the content of the file using the [FileAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and then **console.log()** the content.

For further you can read in much detail about the console.log the content of the file in javascript in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/754398/11926970)

Answer (score -3):

Try using events:

```html
<object data="load.txt"></object>
```

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('object')[0].addEventListener('load', (e)=>{
    // your element should have the data loaded here.

})
```