# Why doesn't Browserify work with fs.readFileSync?

Tags: javascript, browserify, fs

When I run my code:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var text = fs.readFileSync('data.txt').toString().split("\n");

function getDataJS(){
    var i = 0;
    var c = "";
    var d = "";
    var t = "";
    var r = "";
    for(i = 0;i<text.length;i++){
        if(i == 0){
            c = text[i];
            document.getElementById('con').innerHTML = c;
        } else if(i == 1){
            d = text[i]
            document.getElementById('dec').innerHTML = d;
        } else if(i == 2){
            t = text[i]
            document.getElementById('tes').innerHTML = t;
        } else if(i == 3){
            r = text[i]
            document.getElementById('rec').innerHTML = r;
        }
    }
}


module.exports = getDataJS();
```

(with my html)
 I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
```

Does anyone know why this is? I know that node does not work with browsers, but I'm confused why browserify isn't working.

Comment: If you're running this code in a browser, you can't open files from a browser context

Comment: Hey Daniel, the browser doesn't have all the methods that node.js does. And vice versa. Try using the [File API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750032/reading-file-contents-on-the-client-side-in-javascript-in-various-browsers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Browserify](http://browserify.org/):

> Browsers don't have the require method defined, but Node.js does. With Browserify you can write code that uses require in the same way that you would use it in Node.

---

Browserify let's you use `require`. It **doesn't** let you use the APIs provided by Node.js that are not provided by browsers… including those needed to read files from the computer the code is running on.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @DanielOutis — I don't know what you are trying to do. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: I'm trying to feed live data to my website that is updated every 10 minutes from a file 'data.txt'. I have a python file which scrapes the data from a website, then replaces the text in data.txt with the new data, then I need the javascript file to take that data and display it on the html site.

Comment: @DanielOutis does the file get placed on the server? in that case your browser can use AJAX to fetch the contents from the server.

Comment: If you're trying to make a HTTP GET request from JavaScript then you should probably ask a question about that (or do a search, its a common problem).

Comment: the file does get placed on the sftp server. @ADyson

Comment: @Quentin does the http get code go in the html or js?

Comment: @DanielOutis you can't make an FTP or SFTP connection from browser-based code. You need to be able to access the file via HTTP or HTTPS

Comment: @DanielOutis HTML is a visual markup language, it can't be used for programming, so yes the HTTP code would need to be written in the Javascript. I suggest you find a tutorial showing you how to make an AJAX request using the `fetch()` functionality built into all modern browsers.