# Handle a file with js without download

Tags: javascript, html

So let's say I have `<input type="file">` and I click on `<button onclick="code:D()">` what I want is to find the file's name and code with javascript, I can already find the name with `document.getElementById("fileid").files[0];` but I want to see the raw code without a download, how?

Comment: [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: I haven't use this, but https://gist.github.com/gipi/3129800 link might work for you. give it a try

Comment: Raw code ?...do you want to read file content, then look into this [File Reader - SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/754398/11719787)