# VueJS Read/Write JSON on local drive

Tags: json, local-storage, vuejs3

I'm want write a simple one page application that utilizes JSON data stored on a local hard drive.  I will use VueJS V3 for data binding to the HTML page.

The HTML page will be a data entry form that when the user presses the save button, the local JSON data will be updated.

That said, I have no clue within VueJS of how to read/write to a local JSON fie.

Anyone have a simple example to share with me?

Thanks in advance or any help.

Comment: You can't directly access files on the local hard drive from the browser.

Comment: Assuming a browser within the last several years is being used, the following allows the browser to write to the local hard drive.  window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);

Comment: Here is a link to an article that shows a demo working...
https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/how-to-save-form-data-in-a-text-file-using-javascript.htm

Comment: That's why I wrote "directly". The article you linked, opens a download dialog ...

Comment: Interesting, I tried the published code is a test page and it ran without opening a dialog but for my application a dialog would not be a bad thing.  But my present problem is teaching VueJS to read the local saved JSON into a data object.  Any suggestions where I might be able to find that  example?

Comment: Did you configure your browser for a default download location? For reading a file via an `<input type="file">` element you can refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750032/reading-file-contents-on-the-client-side-in-javascript-in-various-browsers