# Drag and drop csv file into Leaflet map

Tags: csv, drag-and-drop, leaflet

Have not to find any solution for Drag and Drop CSV files into a Leaflet map. There is a plugin for GeoJSON, TopoJSON, and zipped Shapefiles [Drag and Drop calvinmetcalf](http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/#7/47.761/3.384).
For those files, you need GIS software or special tools that can convert to these file types. I want a plain CSV file that users can use without having special software.

[Esri](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/samples/exp_dragdrop/) has a function similar to what I'm looking for. A simple drag and drop of CSV onto the map, the CSV of course needs to have lat/lon values to work...

I have been trying with drag and drop function and this plugin [Leaflet.geoCSV](https://github.com/joker-x/Leaflet.geoCSV) using the below script. But not sure how to get the dropped file to interact with the plugin. The file gets uploaded to the browser but can't get the data to show on the map and there are no errors... I am missing something or have got everything wrong...

```
<div id="map" ondrop="dropHandler(event);" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/leaflet.geocsv.js"></script>

 function dragOverHandler(ev) {
  console.log('File(s) in drop zone');

  // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function dropHandler(ev) {
  console.log('File(s) dropped');

  // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
  ev.preventDefault();

  if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
    // Use DataTransferItemList interface to access the file(s)
    for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
      // If dropped items aren't files, reject them
      if (ev.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
        var file = ev.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();
        console.log('... file[' + i + '].name = ' + file.name);
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Use DataTransfer interface to access the file(s)
    for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
      var geoLayer = L.geoCsv(ev.dataTransfer.files[i].name, {firstLineTitles: true, fieldSeparator: ';'});
      map.addLayer(geoLayer);
      geoLayer.addTo(map);
      //console.log('... file[' + i + '].name = ' + ev.dataTransfer.files[i].name);
    }
  }

  // Pass event to removeDragData for cleanup
 // removeDragData(ev)
}

function removeDragData(ev) {
  console.log('Removing drag data')

  if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
    // Use DataTransferItemList interface to remove the drag data
    ev.dataTransfer.items.clear();
  } else {
    // Use DataTransfer interface to remove the drag data
    ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
  }
}

/*
//Example script from Leaflet.geoCSV
(function() {
'use strict';

var map = L.map('mapContainer');

$.get('data.csv', function(csvContents) {
  var geoLayer = L.geoCsv(csvContents, {firstLineTitles: true, fieldSeparator: ','});
  map.addLayer(geoLayer);
});
}); */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the file content to the `L.geoCsv` and not the file name: `L.geoCsv(ev.dataTransfer.files[i].name,` you can do this for example with `FileReader` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/754398/8283938).

PS: This two lines are the same, so you can remove one of them:

```
      map.addLayer(geoLayer);
      geoLayer.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

I manage to get it working, thanks for pointing me to the *FileReader*.
I used the following, if anyone has a similar problem...

```
<div id="map" 
ondrop="dropHandler(event);" 
ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);"></div>

function dragOverHandler(ev) {
console.log('File(s) in drop zone');

// Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
ev.preventDefault();
}

function dropHandler(ev) {
console.log('File(s) dropped');

// Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
ev.preventDefault();

if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
// Use DataTransferItemList interface to access the file(s)
for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
  // If dropped items aren't files, reject them
  if (ev.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
    var file = ev.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        if (reader.readyState != 2 || reader.error){
            return;
      } else {
            convertToLayer(reader.result)       
        }};

reader.addEventListener('progress', (event) => {
if (event.loaded && event.total) {
  const percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  console.log(`Progress: ${Math.round(percent)}`);
}
});       
    reader.readAsText(file)
  }}
}
}

function convertToLayer(CSV) {
var geoLayer = L.geoCsv(CSV, {
    longitudeTitle: 'lng',
    latitudeTitle: 'lat',
    firstLineTitles: true,
    fieldSeparator: ';',
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circle(latlng, {
            radius: 5,
            fillColor: '#969696',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            color: '#252525',
            weight: 1,
            });
}
});
  geoLayer.addTo(map);
}
```